# Как изменить вид блока div?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

хочу спросить совета, как сверстать данный блок? вырезав данную картинку из photoshop или же с помощью css этот блок изменить а если с помощью css то как это реализовать? [image]

Comment: Вы про скошенный блок блок?Если да то ` transform: rotate();`

Comment: да да , про него

Comment: Вот здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861789/  есть примеры реализации подобной верстки с примерами. А вообще, известны 3 метода: clip-path, :before и :after, transform.

Comment: transform искажает не только границы блока, но и его содержимое, так что аккуратнее, хотя и этого можно избежать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0
}


/*стили выше добавлены только для этого примера, в реальном проекте используйте normilize.css\reset.css*/

.box {
  margin: 100px auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-10deg);
  transform: skewY(-10deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Отличный вариант - через прозрачный border у псевдоэлементов.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrGgBY - пример

HTML:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {overflow: hidden;}
.block:before {
  content: '';
  transform: translateY(-100%); 
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 240px solid #333;
  border-right: 500px solid #333;
  border-left: 3000px solid transparent;
}
```