# Возможно ли так сделать?

Tags: html, css

Возможно ли сделать такие границы у блоков без использования фоновых картинок?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через SVG например

Comment: Можете накинуть пример для наглядности, а то я не совсем понимаю как оно с адаптивностью будет сочетаться...

Answer (score 4):

Блок, подобный черному, точно можно, например, при помощи [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).
А можно использовать псевдоэлементы `:before` и `:after`

```css
.block {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}
.wrap {
  width:500px;
  background-color: grey;  
  position: relative;  
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 60px;
}
/* верхний скос */
.wrap::before {  
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-top: 45px solid transparent;
  border-left: 500px solid #333;  
  top: -45px;
}
/* нижний скос */
.wrap::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 500px solid #333;
  bottom: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Если нужен обычный параллелограмм, то можно и `transform` обойтись.

Comment: Посмотрел ваш пример по поводу 2го блока, есть вопрос, а как такое реализовать на лэндинге, что бы ширина блока была 100%, просто если в данном примере изменить ширину, то угол пропадает...

Comment: Скос не пропадает, а уменьшается, становится менее заметным. Нужно изменить параметры border-top, border-left,  top, border-bottom, border-right, bottom. На пробу сейчас изменила для width:1000px, все работает. При процентах же вычислить не проблема.

Comment: @avocado03 в движке есть возможность вставлять сниппеты прямо в ответ

Answer (score 3):

Можно решить через градиенты `linear-gradient()`

```css
.block {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}
.wrap {
  width:500px;
  background-color: grey;  
  position: relative;  
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 60px;
}
/* верхний скос */
.wrap::before {  
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-top: 45px solid transparent;
  border-left: 500px solid #333;  
  top: -45px;
}
/* нижний скос */
.wrap::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 500px solid #333;
  bottom: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```